# Overload resolution C-style strings

Tags: c++, constexpr, overload-resolution

Would it be possible to explain why the following code ain't working as expected? In this case, I would assume that both static_asserts would pass, though the one indicated with `Failed` doesn't seem to be taken.

My understanding of overload resolution would be that the type most closely linked to the argument. As the top definition is a C-Style array, while the bottom definition is a decayed char*; I find it strange that the select overload gets used.

Both MSVC as Clang seem to have the same behavior.

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
note: non-constexpr function 'getStrLen' cannot be used in a constant expression
```

The code:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr auto getStrLen(const char(&str)[N])
    {
    static_assert(N != 0, "Every literal string should have a null terminator");
    return N - 1; // Remove \0
   }
static_assert(getStrLen("") == 0, "Success");

auto getStrLen(const char *str)
    {
   return strlen(str);
    }

static_assert(getStrLen("") == 0, "Failed");
```

Comment: Add a `template <class = void>` to the second overload and you'll get an error that's more insightful :)

Comment: Overload resolution prefers non-`template` functions. I don’t recall the exact rule, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: but isn't the non-`template` function a worse candidate due to the required decay?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I just trawled through the standard and I think I unearthed what makes the function the better match (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exact match and array to pointer conversion have the same rank according to 16.3.3.1.1 [over.ics.scs]/Table 13. A matching non-`template` is preferred over a matching `template` according to 16.3.3 [over.best.match]. In summary, the non-template function taking a `char const*` is the better match.

Making this function a `template`, e.g., by giving it a defaulted `template` parameter may solve the problem. It has a fair chance to make the two function ambiguous.

Comment: *"An exact match and array to pointer conversion have the same rank"* - that seems oddly specific. Why is that rule in place?

Comment: 16.3.3. is `The ## operator` in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I’m not Core person - you’d need to ask one of these! Sadly, the standard doesn’t have a rationale. My *guess* is that it was intentional to avoid template “stealing”overloads by chance but my guess is as good as anybody else’s.

Comment: @JVApen: the current official standard is C++17 and certainly not anything predating even C++14. I did provide stable references, too, for those who consider it opportune to match things against outdated documents.

Comment: Found it, is 13.3.3 in that draft.

Comment: @JVApen: due to some ISO rules three chapters needed to be aded close to the front, i.e., the numbers are generally shifted by 3 between C++14 and C++17. Messes with everybody...